# Is it possible to crack encrypted device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, security, encryption, disk-encryption

I have device powered by Qualcomm MSM8974AC Snapdragon 801 cpu and running Cyanogenmod 13 (6.0.1 android) rom with unlocked bootloader and TWRP (3.0) recovery.
ROM has security patch level December 2016. Device is encrypted by FDE (Full-disk encryption) and using same PIN for lock-screen and booting.

Let's say attacker has full psyhical access to this device. The point of attack is decrypt data. Attacker has unlimited tries of entering password:

```
devicepolicy/java/com/android/server/devicepolicy/DevicePolicyManagerService.java:

DEF_MAXIMUM_FAILED_PASSWORDS_FOR_WIPE = 0
```

Based on [that article](http://bits-please.blogspot.ru/2016/06/extracting-qualcomms-keymaster-keys.html) if am understanding correctly the only possible way is exploiting TrustZone or Keymaster vulnerability and then just bruteforce psyhical dump on powerful machine.

But thats seems like got patched in January 2016 and [May 2016](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2016-05-01.html) security bulletin (CVE-2015-6639
CVE-2015-6647 CVE-2016-2431 CVE-2016-2432)

So the question is it still possible without OEM help of course?

Comment: Most encryption protocol creators are paid by large security agencies to install backdoors, This allows the security agencies quick decryption without needing a powerful computer at all.. It is entirely possible that someone determined and well educated enough could stumble upon these backdoors and hypothetically gain access to any similar encryption from the same source.  I saw somewhere that our information on technology doubles every year, therefore in 20 years our information on technology could be more than 1 million times more than today and one year later 2 Million, never impossible.

Comment: @Zillinium it is entirely possible to do and has been acheived before. Ebaloff could you please provide your device manufacutor, model number, and if the device has usb debugging enabled, if you know, as this can help us, further help you with the specific device.

Comment: Also, i have a device that sound similar to yours but with a locked boot loader and stock recovery, are you using a Samsung with model number SM-S120VL?

Comment: Related: [Data recovery from encrypted phone based on glitches in the encryption?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216410/218526) and [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)