# Wipe data from dead Android phone

Tags: internal-storage, storage, hardware, delete

I have Samsung Galaxy A10s. Now its dead. No power on. I tried lots of combinations. I don't want anybody to get the data, messages or media files which is in internal memory. But as its not charging and not showing drive after connect through USB to PC, I can't delete data directly.

How can I delete media files specially from internal phone memory from my dead phone?

Comment: Related: [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526) and [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)

Comment: what @IrfanLatif wants to say is, your files are secure. it's nearly "impossible" to recover files from locked down/encrypted phone (except for bruteforcing/social engineering)

Comment: @IrfanLatif the thing is phone is not detected by computer

Comment: @alecxs 100% sure data is secured?,I heard it read by odin or other?

Comment: @DeanRox [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526) exactly covers the case when phone is not detected by computer. If it's encrypted, the chances of data recovery are nearly zero. In other case it's very probable.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what has already been suggested in the comments, if you're only interested in destroying the data and not recovering it, you could drill through eMMc to completely destroy it.

It is **HIGHLY** unadvised to do this without careful consideration as your phone contains a lithium ion battery and I shouldn't have to explain the dangers of damaging a battery.

You can follow [this guide](https://www.sosav.com/guides/mobiles/samsung/galaxy-a10/motherboard/) to remove the "motherboard" from the phone.

I'm not certain where the eMMc is located on the chip (the protective casing covers all the components and I've never done a teardown on the phone myself) but, at this point you can sort of just go crazy and destroy the whole thing.

Comment: i guess the purpose of wiping data is giving device to repair shop, not destroying it!

Comment: @x1ras I bought phone in one month ago.Has warranty period,if i tear down warranty will cancel.what can I do?

Comment: @DeanRox My apologies, you're question didn't clarify that you wanted to send the phone for repair or replacement so I answer strictly in terms of making the data unrecoverable.

Have you tried using a different cable to charge you're phone or connect it to your computer?
It may seem like an obvious thing but you be surprised by how many people wouldn't think of this.

Comment: @x1ras I tried,no response

Answer (score 0):

you run latest (bootloader locked) android with all [security features](https://source.android.com/security/features), there is no way to access data with any tools. Only way is try-and-error pin/pattern/password guessing. I don't think repair shop have time for this. there is [Rate limiting](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2014/10/revisiting-android-disk-encryption.html?showComment=1424052022508#c8542808811237981522) one have to wait 30 secs after 10 unsuccessful tries. if attacker manage to repair your device, he could bruteforce a 4 digit pin in ~8 hours. security depends on weakness of your screen lock. a long alphanumeric password would take years. if screen lock is a pattern, data is wiped after 30x unsuccessful attempts.

you can remotely wipe your device/or change screen lock from [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager). as soon as it is connected to internet the changes will apply.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3954855