# Dead phone and lost data

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, boot-loop, reboot

Few weeks ago,my phone has suddenly dead and entered in an endless restart loop.
All data saved in the phone is gone. What I care for the most is  WhatsApp chats and attachments.
I remember I have backed up my WhatsApp chats few months ago ,but I do fail to remember what e mail I have used as I installed WhatsApp on my “late” phone 4 years ago and have changed my emails several times since then.
Is there any method to know the email on which I have backed up the info.
Or is there any method to retrieve the lost data ,escpecially Whatsapp Chats to my PC for instance ? 
Another question : Can I find the messages sent through this period.
Note: I don’t  know if my problem resides within the speciality of this website

Comment: Partial answer: [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/how-to-get-data-off-a-completely-dead-android-phone)

Comment: a friend of me didn't even know SIM pin because she never switched off her device for one year. the email (google account) is bonded to device (FRP) and therefore important security attribute, you should be more careful with credentials (without email password you can't use device anymore after factory reset)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the sim to a different phone and downloading whatsapp in it. Log into the whatsapp with your phone number. It will prompt to retrieve saved data. Make sure you retrieve it otherwise it will be difficult. Whatsapp automatically backs-up the chats.

Comment: As far as I know WhatsApp is deactivated on a  phone whenever installed on another phone with the same number. I am afraid the data would be lost forever then.

Comment: I don’t think chats would  be retrieved as simple as that as the same SIM card might be owned by another person (if one cancels his SIM card it is given to another person) This would be a huge hack to privacy . What I know is that the back up and restore process is related to an email address, which I ,unfortunately ,  fail to remember

Comment: @user261947 Whatsapp deletes everything after 45 days. But if you manage to get access to the phone number before that... https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/24068052/?category=5245246

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921

Comment: If you want to use a local backup, you'll need to transfer the files to the new phone using a computer, file explorer or SD Card.

Note:

Your phone will store up to the last seven days worth of local backup files.
Local backups will be automatically created every day at 2:00 AM and saved as a file in your phone.
If your data isn't stored in the /sdcard/WhatsApp/ folder, you might see "internal storage" or "main storage" folders.