# Possible to perform data recovery with dead cpu? (LG G6 - Android 9)

Tags: encryption, 9.0-pie, lg, disk-encryption, lg-g6

I've got a dead LG G6, suddenly freeze during normal using.
After force rebooting, it was completely dead even though connecting to charging cable.

Have already performed cpu chip-off and reballing, still the same symptoms as before.
The cpu (Qualcomm Snapdragon 821) was found dead and the mechanic told the data is non-retrievable because of the fde with cpu.

```
Research from internet:
- The data partition is encryted with the key stored in cpu
- only replacing normally-function cpu is not possible to power on the device
```

Im wondering if chip-off technique applied to take off the ufs, reading it using a BGA153 reader on computer + brute-force decryption is possible or not.

**The knock code(screen lock) is known, may perform dictionary attack without wild guess.
The screen lock is 6-step knock code.**

Steps:

1. Extracting the full dump as a bin file
2. Performing a brute-force method(hashcat + physical analyzer) to the mounted storage
3. Good news or infinite waiting?

Thats absolutely my bad of not frequently backup the phone, want to make up the fault and retrieve those memory back.

Highly appricated to any advice on the issue, many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/how-to-get-data-off-a-completely-dead-android-phone)

Comment: https://bits-please.blogspot.com/2016/06/extracting-qualcomms-keymaster-keys.html whatever you have read forget it, one can't brute force RSA-2048 key and there is no vulnerability to extract it