# How to know if it's hard bricked or a hardware problem?

Tags: unbricking

**Phone:**

Moto C Plus, rooted.

**How it started:**

I was on F-Droid, downloaded Bromite (a browser). While installing it, the phone froze/hang. I went to the kitchen, came back, and i see the recovery TWRP logo screen. It was just frozen on that logo screen.

**What I did:**

I took out the battery, put it back in, tried to turn it on...nothing. Plug it to the charger...nothing. The computer...nothing.

Took it to a shop. They hooked it up to a power supply...[image: power supply machine]

The reading was 0.7, too low. They said that means it's the AC. I don't know, is a reading of 0.7 not consistent with a hard bricked phone? Or is it a case of replacing or reballing the AC like they said?

I'm willing to do whatever it takes to revive this thing because I need what's in it.

Where do I start?

Comment: If you won't trust the expertise given you, why do you go there? You have the $$$ in your pocket that they want, so it is expected they do what is right for you. Absent another opinion of someone who can actually experiment with the device and diagnose, why would an impersonal, fact-lacking, INTERNET-based, opinion mean more?

Comment: What did they measure? You forgot to mention the unit of the value 0.7, was it Volt, Watt, Ampere, Apples, Bananas?

Comment: @wbogacz because experience my friend. Because this "impersonal, fact-lacking, INTERNET-based, opinion" came through so many times in the past when these so called experts told me its unfixable, or actually messed it up themselves. They are mobile technicians, they are not regulated like doctors. Most do not even know the term "hard bricked" or have the right tools to do the job. So I am always weary

Comment: @Robert Sorry, amps. It was very difficult getting the right info. I asked them what the machine is called, and what they are doing exactly. But they couldn't make it clear. All they said was "not many technicians know how to do this". Which wasn't my question. So I had to guess what it was, get online with that guess and figure out what they were doing. Thats how i found the picture of the device. So yeah, Ampere i deduced.

Comment: But 0.7 Ampere on USB (5V) would be 3.W Watt, which would be a common value for a phone (without charging). So it is still not clear why somebody claims a phone is dead by just reading 0.7A. May be that the phone does not charge is what they wanted to tell you.

Comment: @Robert OK, here is more detail... They hooked up alligator clips to the phone's battery positive and negative terminals. The machine was set to 4 volts (the number which is showing 31.6 in the picture above). Then they press the power button on the phone to see the reading. They said if the phone was good then the number would be above 1. Another guy said 4...but I didn't see what volt it was set on. Something else he said is that as soon as he let go of the power button on the phone, the number should decrease gradually and not instantly like it was doing on my phone. Makes sense to you?

Comment: as your device is rooted, is it by any chance unencrypted? so you can just read back userdata partition from SP Flash Tool (no battery needed)

Comment: @alecxs Hi Alexs, good to hear from you...I'm getting nothing when i connect it to the computer. Not even that windows tone you here when you first connect the phone.

Comment: @alecxs I just did it - lsusb. Not detecting.

Comment: @alecxs Its a USB Live. Tried with battery out. Still nothing. What should i do next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214255/how-to-get-data-off-a-completely-dead-android-phone)

Comment: @alecxs My goal here is to be able to log in normally as what I need are the apps and their data which I'm logged in to and no longer have the passwords or emails connected to them. I've been using them for years without logging out. I did make a nandroid backup but don't know how useful that is since the phone is completely dead. Also the nandroid backup is a bit old. I'm trying to troubleshoot right now to try to figure out what the exact problem is. The link you gave gives 2 options - JTAG and chip-off. I want to be %100 sure those are the required solutions for my particular problem first.

Comment: your phone is dead. Idk how to fix it. if you already have backup just send it to https://www.closingtheloop.eu