# recover smartphone after factory reset

Tags: data-recovery

Last friday, my Samsung smartphone somehow performed a factory reset. I do not know why (it fell on the ground, or my son triggered something, but that does not matter now).

I noticed it when during booting, I saw the samsung letters and after that the 'let's get started' screen where I had to choose a language to setup the phone.
I lost everything that was on my smartphone including some pictures. Most stupid of course, but I know I setup google photos to automatically backup my photos. However, when I checked google online, not 1 image was there so, I lost everything that was on my smartphone. I can live with that for most of the pictures but some I would like to get back somehow.

I tried to recover my data using several apps on my computer. 
dr fone for android, fonelab for android, easeus data recovery.

Dr Fone took some time before completing with saying nothing could be found because I do not have root access on my samsung smartphone.

I already looked into rooting the phone but as far as I could read, rooting would cause a data wipe which I do not.

Is there any chance / method to recover data from my phone and how should I do that? The device is a Samsung A6 SM-A600FN (2018).

Comment: Sorry for your loss but there's no way to recover deleted data without root access. Even with root access, after factory reset, chances aren't very high. Related: [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526) You may contact some professional service but consider factors explained here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216410/218526

Comment: As Irfan says, your data is most likely gone now. It's also worth pointing out that an auto wipe can often be triggered by incorrectly entering the passcode 10 times in a row.

Comment: The trigger for auto wipe, is that a standard setting or does it have to be set by the user when configuring the phone? The auto wipe is the only reason I can come up with for this factory reset to occur.  But I have not set that when I configured my phone.

Comment: @DutchArjo that's not a standard settings on stock Android but OEMs can configure their ROMs to add such features on their devices. Also on managed devices this can be a part of policy. Apps (user or system) with admin rights can also do that.

Comment: I suspect my employer made this a setting then. I will check with them if this is the case. Doesn't help me with getting my files back, but might explain to me how this could happen.

Comment: check your clouds https://photos.google.com or https://drive.google.com/drive/backups maybe there is something left. your history may helpful too https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity

Comment: I did, there was nothing there. I had a phone backup from the evening before so some files are recovered, but I do not care about these files. I hoped google photos had backupped but did not backup anything. I have now reset my phone and configured it again.

Comment: completely surprised: my phone is reconfigured, I opened google photos to enable backup, and suddenly I have all my photos back...