# Are there any downsides to encrypting an Android device?

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption, privacy, disk-encryption

Besides requiring a lock screen, are there any downsides to encrypting an Android device (using the native encryption)?

For example:

- is there a performance decrease?
- is there a temperature increase?
- is there a battery consumption increase?
- are there any data integrity issues?
- does it make anything more difficult (besides requiring a lock screen)?

Comment: What kind of encryption? FBE or FDE? In one you need to enter your password to even access your basic phone functions

Comment: @beeshyams I'm open to both possibilities.

Comment: Theoretically there should be somewhat impact on performance, temperature and battery. But that's negligible, and even unnoticeable even if you try to observe. A downside is difficulty in data recovery when password/key goes wrong or phone is dead. It's obviously a trade-off between security/privacy and data recoverability.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Recovery on a dead phone is an interesting concern I hadn't thought about sufficiently.  Is there no standard way to accomplish this, given that you have the correct password?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard no. Password isn't of any use due to hardware-backed encryption. See [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Upvoted! Even if you can get in to a bootloader, it sounds like the password would not help, since the encryption is hardware-backed.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard correct. But there are some proof of concept hacks that worked in past for brute-forcing the encryption when the device was able to boot into bootloader stage at least. But such possibilities are near to none. // Also an accidental factory reset over encryption makes data recovery nearly impossible. See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216410/218526

Comment: please note hardware-backed encryption is not a protection for unlocked or by-passed bootloader - once you get in, the only protection is screen lock password! even worse a lot devices do not even use screen lock credentials (they simply use *default_password* for **FDE**)