# Why isn't the unlock pattern working anymore?

Tags: security, lock-screens, encryption, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-8

A few days ago my unlock pattern was not recognized anymore. I'm guessing the cause is memory corruption or some bug.

I haven't restarted the device yet, hoping to "find" the new pattern or somehow bypass the screen lock.

The device is not rooted and "require PIN when device powers on" is disabled. Firmware is G950FXXS5DSJ1 build date Sep 30 2019.

It is encrypted:

```
> adb shell getprop | find "crypto"

[ro.crypto.fde_algorithm]: [AES-256-XTS-DISK]
[ro.crypto.fs_crypto_blkdev]: [/dev/block/dm-1]
[ro.crypto.fuse_sdcard]: [true]
[ro.crypto.state]: [encrypted]
[ro.crypto.type]: [block]
```

##### What I've tried

***Google device manager*** - can only reset the device for non-enterprise accounts.

***Samsung FindMyDevice*** - can change the PIN if enabled in the settings - disabled it for security reasons.

**"Guessing" the PIN** - I've tried feeding all the possible combinations to

```
adb.exe shell locksettings verify --old xxxxxx
```

The response is always "Old password 'xxxxxx' didn't match". Strangely, it's not throttling (tested the same method with an Android 10 device and immediately got "Request throttled"). Might be related to missing files (more below).

**Looking at logs**  - since ADB is working, I've tried looking at `adb.exe logcat -b system`, but have no idea what to look for.

Some  suspicious messages:

```
LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/fmmpassword.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system_de/0/spblob/xxxxxxxxxxxx.weaver: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I understand `/data/system_de/0/spblob/xxxxxxxxxxxx.weaver` is used in the password verification.

Looking at `/data/system/` some files might be missing (I've read that unlock data is stored in `gatekeeper*` files which I can't find, maybe because of insufficient permissions):

```
1|dreamlte:/ $ ls /data/system/
ls: /data/system//hdcp2_5386: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//users: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//container: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//ndebugsocket: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//secure_storage: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//.aasa: Permission denied
ls: /data/system//heapdump: Permission denied
HWParamTime.bin                 dropbox                       locksettings.db-shm         screen_on_time
SimCard.dat                     enterprise                    locksettings.db-wal         sensor_big_data.txt
WifiHistory.db                  enterprise.conf               log-files.xml               sensor_big_data_usage.txt
WifiHistory.db-journal          enterprise.db                 mobeam_big_data_usage.txt   sensor_service
analytics.db                    enterprise.db-journal         netpolicy.xml               shared_prefs
analytics.db-journal            enterprise.db-shm             netstats                    shortcut_service.xml
appops.xml                      enterprise.db-wal             notification_log.db         slice
audioservice_sec.db             enterprise_cacerts.bks        notification_log.db-journal slocation.db
audioservice_sec.db-journal     enterprise_nativecerts.bks    notification_policy.xml     slocation.db-journal
battery-saver                   enterprise_untrustedcerts.bks overlays.xml                slocation.db-se
batterystats-checkin.bin        enterprise_usercerts.bks      package-cstats.list         sound_model.db
batterystats-daily.xml          entropy.dat                   package-dex-usage.list      sound_model.db-journal
batterystats.bin                friends                       package-usage.list          startingwindow
big_data_sensor_usage_pkg.txt   gamemanager.db                package_cache               storage.xml
big_data_usage_call_gesture.txt gamemanager.db-journal        packages-warnings.xml       sync
cachequota.xml                  graphicsstats                 packages.list               timezone
clipboardimage.db               harmony_third_party_apps.xml  packages.xml                ucm_ca_cert
clipboardimage.db-journal       hcm_info                      packages.xml.mbak           uiderrors.txt
conventionalmode                hcm_info-journal              pda.db                      urigrants.xml
device_policies.xml             ifw                           pda.db-journal              usagestats
deviceidle.xml                  inputmethod                   pre_boot_csc.dat            watchlist_report.db
diskstats_cache.json            install_sessions              procstats                   watchlist_report.db-journal
display-manager-state.xml       install_sessions.xml          recoverablekeystore         watchlist_settings.xml
displaysolution.db              job                           recoverablekeystore.db      wifigeofence.db
displaysolution.db-journal      last-fstrim                   recoverablekeystore.db-shm  wifigeofence.db-journal
dmappmgr.db                     last-header.txt               recoverablekeystore.db-wal
dmappmgr.db-journal             locksettings.db               registered_ucm_services
```

What can I do to understand what happened?

Will restarting restore the pattern or cause even more problems?

Comment: Is there any possibility of this being a prank from a friend that was able to unlock your phone? That would be my first guess...

Comment: A Galaxy S8 on Android 9 should always be encrypted (by default). Why do you think it is not encrypted?

Comment: Some pointers on how to get around that can be found in [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) – not sure which ones are still working, though.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado no way, as it worked the evening before, then when I woke up I got "Incorrect pattern drawn". The device was with me all the time.

Comment: @Robert I might be confusing internal storage encryption with something else. The phone was on Android 8 (encryption definitely not activated) and then I upgraded OTA to Android 9. On reboot, the phone starts without me having to enter the unlock pattern.

Comment: Hi @alecxs, I meant to say "internal storage is not encrypted" - edited the post to clarify. If it's incompatible with rooting, I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the suggestion, it's a really old post, mostly out of date or requiring root. Some suggestions I've already tried (updated the post accordingly).

Comment: @Robert I had activated internal data encryption manually years ago on a different S8 that was on Android 7 (I think), it was a lengthy process. On this device I didn't notice the encryption process when upgrading to Android 9. I remember though having an option in settings - "require PIN when device powers on" which is disabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data recovery from encrypted phone based on glitches in the encryption?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215970/data-recovery-from-encrypted-phone-based-on-glitches-in-the-encryption)

Comment: I've restarted and `/data/system/fmmpassword.key` magically reappeared. I guess this is why unlock broke.

I'll post an answer with some info that if I had known at the beginning would have made this less of a pain and a time drain.  

I've spent about a day only to figure out downloading from `/storage/emulated/0` with adb. Thanks @Robert, @Izzy for sharing your expertise. @alecxs very informative and to the point   the shared presentation Android encryption vs Samsung's "I did it my way" was very interesting (and hilarious - SD card decryption key readable by the world *facepalm*).